# SQL Server - Need Single query which performs Select or Update based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table `Order` with columns `Id` and `amount`.

I need a query which returns all the records where amount > 200, and if amount < 200, it should update amount and return amount.

```
ID    Amount
1     250
2     190
3      50
4     200
```

Now I need single query 
which `select sum(amount) from order where amount > 200`  for `Id` 1 and 4

but for 2 and 3 it should fire Update query `Update order set amount = 200 where amount < 200`
 first and then it should fire `select sum(amount) from order where amount > 200`

Hope i am clear with requirement this time

Please help me.

Comment: what does *update amount and return amount* mean?

Comment: Update amount *to what?*

Comment: return amount means "select amount from Order" and Update amount means Update query for updating amount.

Comment: And what should be returned for amounts `<200` (and what about `==200`)?

Comment: Please illustrate what you're trying to accomplish with sample data.  There's a lot of ambiguity here, and I don't like assuming things.

Comment: it sould select all amount > 200 and update all amount <= 200

Comment: Rik you are just repeating yourself, Siyual has a good suggestion how about showing up some sample data and results you desire?  For example we have no idea what value you would want to update amount to when <= 200.........

Comment: @Rik, really! Try to think with a foreigners head: Select all `>200` is easy, you've solved this already. But *update all amount `<=200`* is meaningless... You update a row to change values.... What do you want to change?

Comment: You keep repeating "it sould select all amount > 200 and update all amount <= 200" but sadly that doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to execute a select statement or an update?

Comment: ok, let me edit question with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of a WHERE clause? You almost wrote the solution in your last update.

```
Update order set amount = 200 
Where Amount <= 200;

select sum(amount) 
from order
where Amount > 200
```

My question is are you sure you want to update your order table like this?

Comment: I need single select query which performes updation also.

Comment: i was trying to use IF Else and WHEN CASE but it wasn't helpfull

Comment: Is it possible to Update if amount < 200 and Select if amount > 200

Comment: Nothing is going to work here with a single statement. There is no possible way to perform an update and a select in a single query. There is not some kind of clever work around here. This is like trying to drive backwards and forwards at the same time. It simply CAN NOT be done. Period. End of story.

Comment: @Rik, if you **do not need the values to be stored persistently** you can let it **look like** the thing you need with something like `SELECT CASE WHEN Amount<=200 THEN 200 ELSE Amount END AS Amount;` This will show a result as you want it, **but it will not touch the underlying values!!!**

Comment: I have already done that, but your suggestion is same as i did this. so please post this as an answer i will accept this answer.